# ETL Processing Design and Performance

Tags: c#, sql, database, etl

I am working on a ETL process for a data warehouse using C#, that supports both SQL Server and Oracle.  During development I have been writing stored procedures that would synchronize data from one database to another database. The stored procedures code are rather ugly because it involves dynamic SQL. It needs to build the SQL strings since we have dynamic database name.

My team lead want to use C# code to do the ETL. We have code generation that automatic generate new classes when database definition changes. That's also why I decided not to use Rhino ETL.

Here are the pros and cons:

Stored Procedure:

Pros:

- fast loading process, everything is handled by the database
- easy deployment, no compiling is needed

Cons

- poor readability due to dynamic SQL
- Need to maintain both T-SQL and PL/SQL scripts when database definition changes
- Slow development because no intellisense when writing dynamic SQL

C# Code:

Pros:

- easier to develop the ETL process because we get intellisense from our generated class
- easier to maintain because of generated class
- better logging and error handling

Cons:

- slow performance compare with stored procedure

I would prefer to use application code to do the ETL process, but the performance was horrible compare with stored procedures. In one test when I tries to update 10,000 row. The stored procedures took only 1 sec, while my ETL code took 70s.  Even I somehow manage to reduce the overhead, 20% of the 70s are purely calling update statement from application code.

Could someone provide me suggestions or comment on how to speed up the ETL process using application code?

My next idea is try doing parallel ETL process by opening multiple database connections and perform the update and insert.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you have code generation that automatically generates new classes - why don't you have code generation that automatically generate new stored procedures?

That should give you the best of two worlds; encapsulate it into a few nice classes that can inspect the database and update things as necessary and you can, well not increase readability, but hide it (you would not need to update the SPs manually)

Also, the difference should not be so huge, sounds as if you are not doing something right (reusing connections, moving data unnecessary from server to the application or processing data in smaller batches - row by row?).

Also, regarding better logging - care to elaborate on that? You can have logging on the database layer, too, or you can design your SPs so that application layer can still do the logging.

Comment: We actually has considered it. Unfortunately do the time constraint, we decided to drop this idea for now.. Ideally we want to create a store procedure template and have the code generation code to fill in the columns name and the joins statement, since these column definition changes very often.

Comment: Well, depending on how fancy you want to be, you could use KISS principle and for example take 15 minutes, write that template, connect to database schema and select tables and columns from it with SQL, fill in some table with that list of columns and tables, mark the tables that you actually want and loop over those to fill the template and create the script that will create your SPs. Take backup of schema and then run the script. In case you have more than 100 tables and if you don't know how to query the schema I do agree that it would take closer to two hours. When things change repeat.

Answer (score 2):

If your C# code is already slow with 10,000 rows, I cannot imagine it in a real environement...

Most ETL are done either within the database ([stored procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure), packages, or even compiled within the database (PL/SQL, Java for Oracle)). They can handle millions of rows.

Or some professional tools can be used (Informatica, or others), but it will still be slower than stored procedures, but easier to manage.

So my conclusion is: If you want to come anywhere close to stored procedure performances, you will have to code an application as good as those professional ones on the market, that took years to develop and mature... Do you think you can?

Plus, if you have to handle different database types ([SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), Oracle), you CANNOT make a generic application AND optimize it at the same time, it's a choice. Because Oracle does not work the same way SQL Server does.

To give you an idea, in ETLs for Oracle, hints are used (like the Parallel Execution hints), and also some indexes may be dropped or integrity disabled temporarly to optimize the ETL.

There is no way that I know of to the the exact same thing in SQL Server (they might have similar options, but different syntax).
So "one ETL for all databases" can hardly be done without losing efficiency and speed.

So I think your pros and cons are very accurate; you have to choose between speed and ease of development, but not both.

Comment: You are right, it is a choice of performance vs maintainability. We actually planning to have a hybrid, for data that general has more than 10,000, we are going to do it in store procedure. My concernis that 70s vs 1s is too much even for 10,000 rows. Currently our application haven't take advantage of any feature provided by MSSQL or Oracle. The app only does standard SQL stuffs. I know that once we have to take advantage of special feature, there will be more abstraction layers.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider tuning up your application.

A few tricks of mine:

- Don't use connection.Open() and conenction.Close() too much.
- Im some cases LINQ will slow things down
- Use a procedure and pass more parameters when loading to reduce the number of calls, for example, `proc_load_to_table(p1 text)` change to `proc_load_to_table(p1 text, p2 text, p3 text, p4 tex, p5 text)`